# Convergence conditions

Tags: real-analysis

While studying for my exam in real analysis, I came up with the following problem. Given two sequences $\{a_n\}\to 0$ and $\{b_n\}\to\infty$. What should be the weakest condition so that
$$\sum a_n b_n^p <\infty$$ and $$\sum a_n b_n^q =\infty$$ where $1\le p<q<\infty$. This seems to be quite easy but it turned out to be more technical than I thought. 
Notice that $\{a_n\}$ cannot be $\{\frac{1}{n}\}$ or anything that $\sum a_n$ doesn't converge by itself. So the first condition would be the series $\sum a_n<\infty$.

I was able to give a condition for $a_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$ but I then basically think that I don't have any good idea for the general case.

Comment: Are $a_n,b_n \ge 0$?

Comment: In general, no. However, eventually $b_n > 0$ so I guess we can assume $b_n\ge 0$.
But I would be extremely happy if one can have a condition for $a_n,b_n\ge 0$.